# Voltage time graph integration

Tags: voltage, current, input, time

[image: Voltage-time]In a Voltage time graph , at constant current I= 170 amps, voltage=0 to 5,5 and time= 0 to 97 sec and voltage decreases from 5,5 at 0sec to 1,16 at 97 sec, now how can I find the total power consumption wrt time in this case and in a compley system how can we find power losses in the cables or circut please some one help me out. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please add the graph into your question and fix the punctuation, show your work so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Instantaneous power is the (instantaneous) product of voltage and current. When you ask "how much is the power input to the circuit" and "how can we find power losses in the system", it's like asking if it's raining at your hometown without telling us where is your hometown. If it's more of a "theoretical question", then keep in mind that energy conservation is a thing.

Comment: I was trying a resistive heating on a material

Comment: That doesn't show the work you did, only a repetition of the problem, on paper.

Comment: But how can we do integration of that shaded area?

Comment: No one said anything about integrals. There is a difference between the concepts of 'power' and 'energy'. Also, integration of an exponential function is arguably the easiest integral to solve. (-1) because of no effort shown so far.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, can you please help me find the shaded area under the curve please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Power  = volts x amps.

And, given that the current is constant at 170 amps, you can multiply your voltage graph by 170 to get a power graph (watts) versus time.

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, can you please help me find the shaded area under the curve please. Thank you

Comment: @Pru "shaded area under the curve" = maths problem and not an EE problem. You need to find the average voltage of your waveform over the 97 seconds (hint).